# Issue creating IEEE Xplore-compatible document: accepted with caution

Tags: conference, ieee

I am currently submitting an already accepted paper to an IEEE conference. I validated the paper with the [PDF eXpress tool](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/pdfexpress.html). However, my paper is accepted with caution. The warning message received via e-mail is the following one.

> PDF links are allowed for supplemental electronic material (multimedia) only. ALL OTHER LINKS WILL BE DELETED BEFORE POSTING TO IEEE XPLORE.

If I understand the message correctly, for the document to be IEEE Xplore-compatible, it requires me to cancel all links that are not PDFs. However, many of my sources are links to other sources (e.g., GitHub or an official wiki).

What I am supposed to do? Simply upload the file as it is and wait for editors' complaints?

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite the paper without hyperlinking.  If you want to refer to a wiki or github, use a typed citation.

Comment: e.g., replace a \url with \texttt